# Using ReadableStream with POST using fetch API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fetch

I am trying to do a POST request with the `fetch()` API. I pass an instance of `ReadableStream` as request body as suggested on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Instead of posting data from the stream, the ReadableStream object is just converted to string (resulting in the string `[object ReadableStream]`) and set as request body (see Wireshark frame below).

How correctly connect stream APIs with fetch?

Note: tested in Chrome Version 78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit).

Minimal example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    <script>
        class StreamBuffer {

            constructor() {
                this.data = new Uint8Array(0);
                this.onChunk = null;
            }

            addBinaryData(uint8Array) {
                const newData = new Uint8Array(this.data.length + uint8Array.length);
                newData.set(this.data, 0);
                newData.set(uint8Array, this.data.length);
                this.data = newData;

                if (typeof this.onChunk === 'function') {
                    this.onChunk(this.data);
                    this.data = new Uint8Array(0);
                }
            }
        }

        class BufferedStream {
            constructor(streamBuffer) {
            const buffer = streamBuffer;

            this.readable = new ReadableStream({
                    start(controller) {
                        buffer.onChunk = chunk => controller.enqueue(chunk);
                        buffer.onClose = () => controller.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        const button = document.querySelector('#btn');
        const buffer = new StreamBuffer();
        const readWriter = new BufferedStream(buffer);
        const readable = readWriter.readable;

        button.onclick = function() {
            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint';
            fetch(url, {method: "POST", body: readable});
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From Wireshark:

```
Frame 4: 412 bytes on wire (3296 bits), 412 bytes captured (3296 bits) on interface 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 6, Src: ::1, Dst: ::1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 55785, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 348
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
Line-based text data: text/plain (1 lines)
    [object ReadableStream]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that Chrome is still in the process of implementing this feature. See [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688906)